# Source only part of a script from another script?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, function

This would probably never be the BEST approach to something, but I'm wondering if it's even possible.

Something like:

```
awk '/function_i_want_to_call/,/^$/{print}' script_containing_function | xargs source

function_i_want_to_call arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Except actually working.

Comment: The difference between `source` or `.` (dot) and just executing a script is whether it is done in your original shell process or in a new (subshell) process. For permanently setting variables or other shell properties (like `cd`) you need the first, which the answers address. If you **only need to execute the commands** you can pipe to a new shell like `awk '/select/,/lines/' script | sh`.

Comment: Right, I'm aware of that.  Though it just occurred to me that if the variables needed to be set are in the parent shell, they could be passed through with "export" and then just calling the other script normally.  But it was the "only *part* of the other script" that was the focus of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to rigorously determine what command will produce the specific part you want to source. For a trivial example, given the file

```
var1=value1
var2=value2
```

you could set only `var1` using `head -n1 filename`. This could be a pipeline of arbitrary complexity, if you wanted.

Then run:

```
source <( pipeline_of_arbitrary_complexity some_filename )
```

Works only in `bash`. To do it in POSIX, I think you'd need to make a temp file.

Comment: I didn't realize `<( command )` was `bash`-specific.  But that's definitely the simplest answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In bash/ksh and similar, you can use `<()` to avoid the subshell that `|` creates:

**insourcable.sh**:

```
echo hallo welt
echo hello world
echo ahoj světe
```

Suppose you only want to in-source line number two:

```
. <( sed -n '2 p' < insourcable.sh )
```

(prints "hello world")

Comment: @mikeserv  was alluding to what the OP was trying to do in the question, namely source in from the right-hand side of a pipeline. Obviously, it wouldn't work with xargs but it could work with something like `echo echo foo | . /dev/stdin` but that wouldn't be very useful because what's on the right hand side of a this pipeline is a subshell that cannot affect the parent shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
dotfn(){ . /dev/fd/0
} <<IN
        $(printf '\n%s(){ "$@" '"'\n" "$2"
          sed   -e"/$2.*{/,\$!d;s/^/    /"\
                -e"/^. *} *$/q;s/'/'"'\\&&/g'  <"$1"
          printf "\n';}")
IN
```

obviously it's not fool proof, but it scans a file named in its first argument for the first series of input that begins with its second arg followed at some point on the same line with a `{` and pulls in all following lines until it encounters one which only matches blank space and a single `}`.

while `sed` does so it escapes all hard-quotes in input, and `printf` wraps the input in two hard-quotes and also prepends it with the string `"$@"`. it sticks all of this in a function named for your second argument. here's an example:

```
printf '
some_fn(){
        echo some stuff
        cat </dev/null
}

another_fn(){
        for f in file*; do printf '\''%s\n'\'' "$f"; done
}
' >fn_file
```

i put those two functions in *`fn_file`*, and then...

```
dotfn fn_file another_fn
```

...nothing happened. but...

```
another_fn printf %s\\n
```

---

```
another_fn(){
    for f in file*; do printf '%s\n' "$f"; done
}
```

i enclosed the function within one named for itself, and i can inspect it with `printf` or whatever, or i can redefine it:

```
another_fn eval; another_fn
```

---

```
file
file1.tsv
file1.txt
file2.tsv
file2.txt
filea.xyz
fileb.xyz
```

I replaced the `. /dev/fd/0` in `dotfn()` with a simple `cat` and went after `some_fn()`:

```
dotfn fn_file some_fn
```

---

```
some_fn(){ "$@" '
    some_fn(){
        echo some stuff
        cat </dev/null
    }

';}
```